# Pig: efficient filtering by loaded list

Tags: apache-pig

In Apache Pig (version 0.16.x), what are some of the most efficient methods to filter a dataset by an existing list of values for one of the dataset's fields?

For example,
(Updated per @inquisitive_mind's tip)

Input: a line-separated file with one value per line
my_codes.txt

```
'110'
'100'
'000'
```

sample_data.txt

```
'110', 2
'110', 3
'001', 3
'000', 1
```

Desired Output

```
'110', 2
'110', 3
'000', 1
```

Sample script

```
%default my_codes_file 'my_codes.txt'
%default sample_data_file 'sample_data.txt'
my_codes = LOAD '$my_codes_file' as (code:chararray)
sample_data = LOAD '$sample_data_file' as (code: chararray, point: float)
desired_data = FILTER sample_data BY code IN (my_codes.code);
```

Error:

```
Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : ('110'), 2nd :('100') 
(common cause: "JOIN" then "FOREACH ... GENERATE foo.bar" should be "foo::bar" )
```

I had also tried `FILTER sample_data BY code IN my_codes;` but the "IN" clause seems to require parenthesis. 
I also tried `FILTER sample_data BY code IN (my_codes);` but got the error:
*A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar*

Comment: Follow-up: If the existing list is small in comparison to the dataset being queried, a *replicated* join in Pig is more efficient than a standard JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The my_codes.txt file has the codes as a row instead of a column.Since you are loading it into a single field the codes should be like this below

```
'110'
'100'
'000'
```

Alternatively,you can use JOIN

```
joined_data = JOIN sample_date BY code,my_codes BY code;
desired_data = FOREACH joined_data GENERATE $0,$1;
```

Comment: Additionally, it seems computationally-favorable to prefer Filter to Join, but they may be as equally intensive in this case (e.g. if my_codex.txt contains 1 billion records)?

Comment: Yes,filter is favorable.I doubt "IN" would work because in the earlier versions of PIG,you had to explicitly specify the values separated by comma and enclosed in parenthesis.

Comment: Correct. Even with later versions that have it, "IN" does not seem practical if my_codes > 1000 values. Hence, your JOIN solution seems best