# pyspark: isin vs join

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What are general best-practices to filtering a dataframe in pyspark by a given list of values? Specifically:

Depending on the size of the given list of values, then with respect to runtime when is it best to use `isin` vs inner `join` vs 
`broadcast`?

This question is the spark analogue of the following question in Pig:

[Pig: efficient filtering by loaded list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532143/pig-efficient-filtering-by-loaded-list)

Additional context:

[Pyspark isin function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444632/pyspark-isin-function)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Considering

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
```

There are two types of broadcasting:

- `sc.broadcast()` to copy python objects to every node for a more efficient use of `psf.isin`
- `psf.broadcast` inside a `join` to copy your pyspark dataframe to every node when the dataframe is small: `df1.join(psf.broadcast(df2))`. It is usually used for cartesian products (CROSS JOIN in pig).

In the context question, the filtering was done using the column of another dataframe, hence the possible solution with a join.

Keep in mind that if your filtering list is relatively big the operation of searching through it will take a while, and since it has do be done for each row it can quickly get costly.

Joins on the other hand involve two dataframes that will be sorted before matching, so if your list is small enough you might not want to have to sort a huge dataframe just for a filter.

Comment: I get the two different types of broadcast, but I'm not sure I am clear on the answer to the original question about efficiently _filtering a dataframe in pyspark by a given list of values_. Can I simplify this by saying if the _list of values_ is "small", use `isin` and if the list of values is "big" use inner join with the values in a DataFrame?

Comment: This is what I meant yes: `isin` if the filtering list is small, `join` if it's big . `Broadcast`ing allows you to make your `isin` or `join` (whichever one you chose) even more performant

Comment: it's still not clear what's meant by 'small', 'big'

Comment: @justincress exactly what is on my mind, how small is small and how big is big ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is `sc.brodcast()` and how to use it with `psf.isin` ?

Answer (score 5):

Both join and isin works well for all my daily workcases.

1. isin works well both of small and little large (~1M) set of list.

Note - If you have a large dataset (say ~500 GB) and you want to do filtering and then processing of filtered dataset, then

1. using isin the data read/processing is significantly very low and Fast. Whole 500 GB will not be loaded as you have already filtered the smaller dataset from .isin method.
2. But for the Join case, whole 500GB will loaded and processing. So Time of Processing will be much higher.

My case, After filtering using

1. isin, and then processing and converting to Pandas DF. It took < 60 secs
2. with JOIN and then processing and converting to Pandas DF. It takes > 1 hours.

Comment: "isin works well both of small and little large (~1M) set of list." but then you also states it is the same for large sets too. So did you mean ""isin works well both of small and large(all kind of datasets)"? also little large is termed in M while large is termed in GB. how do you compare?

Comment: Hi, 
1M is the length of list which we want to do filtering. in the question too author has written given list of values. So 1M is the length of this list. 

While 500GB is for the spark dataframe itself.