# PySpark: filtering with isin returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Context:** 
I need to filter a dataframe based on what contains another dataframe's column using the **isin** function.

For Python users working with pandas, that would be: *isin()*.
For R users, that would be: *%in%*.

So I have a simple spark dataframe with **id** and **value** columns:

```
l = [(1, 12), (1, 44), (1, 3), (2, 54), (3, 18), (3, 11), (4, 13), (5, 78)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['id', 'value'])
df.show()

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|   12|
|  1|   44|
|  1|    3|
|  2|   54|
|  3|   18|
|  3|   11|
|  4|   13|
|  5|   78|
+---+-----+
```

I want to get all ids that appear multiple times. Here's a dataframe of unique ids in df:

```
unique_ids = df.groupBy('id').count().where(col('count') < 2)
unique_ids.show()

+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  5|    1|
|  2|    1|
|  4|    1|
+---+-----+
```

So the logical operation would be:

```
 df = df[~df.id.isin(unique_ids.id)]
 # This is the same than:
 df = df[df.id.isin(unique_ids.id) == False]
```

However, I get an empty dataframe:

```
df.show()

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
+---+-----+
```

This "error" works in the opposite way:

```
df[df.id.isin(unique_ids.id)]
```

returns all the rows of df.

Comment: Don't use `isin` here- use `join`. For example: `df.join(unique_ids, on="id").show()`. You can only use `isin` with literal values (ex: `df.where(df["id"].isin([1, 2, 3]))`), not with a column.

Comment: Related/Possible dupes: [Pyspark isin function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709729/5858851), [PySpark: match the values of a DataFrame column against another DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42547745/5858851), [pyspark: isin vs join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803888/pyspark-isin-vs-join)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expression `df.id.isin(unique_ids.id) == False` is evaluating if `Column<b'((id IN (id)) = false)'>` and this will never happen because *id is in id*. However, the expression `df.id.isin(unique_ids.id)` is evaluating if `Column<b'(id IN (id))'>`, and this is always true, for that reason it returns the whole data frame. `unique_ids.id` is a Column not a list.

`isin(*cols)` receives a **list of values** as an argument, not a column, so, to work in this way, you should execute the following:

```
ids = unique_ids.rdd.map(lambda x:x.id).collect()
df[df.id.isin(ids)].collect() # or show...
```

and you will obtain:

```
[Row(id=2, value=54), Row(id=4, value=13), Row(id=5, value=78)]
```

In any case, I think it would be better if you join both data frames:

```
df_ = df.join(unique_ids, on='id')
```

getting:

```
df_.show()
+---+-----+-----+
| id|value|count|
+---+-----+-----+
|  5|   78|    1|
|  2|   54|    1|
|  4|   13|    1|
+---+-----+-----+
```