# filtering with ~isin returns empty dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I need to filter a dataframe based on `NOT IN` condition in SQL.

```
+---+-------+
| id|id_type|
+---+-------+
|  1|     12|
|  1|      8|
|  2|      4|
|  3|      4| *
|  3|      8| *
|  4|      8|
|  5|     11|
+---+-------+
```

```
cond = df.filter(df.id_type.isin([12, 8]).dropDuplicates(['id'])
df.filter(~df.id.isin(cond.id)).dropDuplicates(['id']).count()
```

This returns count 0, empty df.

I think it is the same issue in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046432/pyspark-filtering-with-isin-returns-empty-dataframe), but it is different in that it is `~isin`, not `isin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Instead of passing a DataFrame inside `isin()` function, try passing an array.

1. Your DataFrame

```
+---+-------+
| id|id_type|
+---+-------+
|  1|     12|
|  1|      8|
|  2|      4|
|  3|      4|
|  3|      8|
|  4|      8|
|  5|     11|
+---+-------+
```

2. Convert your filtered df into an array format

```
unique_df = df.filter(df["id_type"].isin([12,8])).drop_duplicates(["id"])

unique_list = unique_df.rdd.map(lambda row: row[0]).collect()
```

3. Use this list in the next `isin`  transformation

```
df.filter( ~df["id"].isin(unique_list) ).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+
| id|id_type|
+---+-------+
|  2|      4|
|  5|     11|
+---+-------+
```